# Ruby - Send hash data created in one class's method to another class's method for further processing this hash data

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I have one class, that in its methods produce an output of a hash.
=> {"A"=>"1", "B"=>"2"}

My question is how can I send this produced hash to another class, with methods that will further process this hash data?

Ive read the ruby doc and searched on StackOverflow, but can't seem to figure out how to get this new class to pick up this data (from the original class).
I am getting "undefined local variable or method" error when attempting to call on the methods of the first class, while in the second class.

Thanks for your help on this.
Hopefully I supplied enough background on my issue that someone can provide some guidance.

EDIT--
Here is the code that I have, which produces a this above mentioned hash. Actually at this stage it's an array. 
Ideally I would like to have all the code from `build_list` method, on downwards, to be in a totally separate class. Doing this would require me to pass the produced array data (from user input) to these other methods, in this new class. In this new class I would like to have the completed playlist printed. So I would like to spit this example code into two classes, with the second class doing all of the processing work on the user supplied artists. I hope this is clearer.

```
require 'lib/uri.rb'
require 'json'
require 'rest_client'
require 'colorize'

class Playlist
  attr_accessor :artistInput, :artist_list

  def initialize
    @artistInput = artistInput
    @artist_list = []
    @artist = @artist


  end

  def self.start #welcome to the application + rules
    puts "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    puts "|This Playlist Creator application will create you a static playlist from a given list of artists supplied by you.|".colorize(:color => :white, :background => :black)
    puts "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    puts "Hint: To stop adding artists, type '\N\' + the [enter] key at any time."
    # puts "Hint: For artists with spaces, eg \'Lady Gaga\' - please remove the spaces and write as such \'LadyGaga\'."
  end
system "clear"
  def artistInput #loop that creates an artist_list array of an infinate amount of artists, stops at the keyword 'N'
    @artist_list = []

    while @artist != ""
      puts "\nWhat artist would you like to add to the Playlist?"
      @artist = gets.gsub(/\s+/, "")
      if @artist != 'N'
      puts "You have chosen to add #{@artist} to the Playlist."
      end
      break if @artist =~ /N/
      @artist_list << @artist.gsub(/\s+/, "") #.gsub removes spaces. 'Lady Gaga'  => 'LadyGaga'
    end

  def build_list
    #@artist_list
    list = @artist_list
    list.join('&artist=')
  end

  def build_url_string
  string = build_list
  url = 'http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/playlist/static?api_key=G3ABIRIXCOIGGCCRQ&artist=' + string
  end
system "clear"
  def parse_url
    url = build_url_string
    response = JSON.parse(RestClient.get url)  

    song = response['response']['songs'].each do |song|
    song.delete("artist_id")
    song.delete("id")
    puts
    song.each {|key, value| puts "#{key.colorize(:white)}: \'#{value.colorize(:color => :white, :background => :black)}\'" }
  end
    # a = response['response']['songs']
    # a.fetch('id')
  end



  a = parse_url
puts "\nThere are #{a.length} songs in this Playlist\n\n" 




#Uncomment this section to see the raw data feed
# puts "////////////////raw data hash feed//////////////"
# puts "#{a.to_s}"

  end 


end
```

Comment: Pass it as an argument to the function you're invoking. Please post some code if that isn't enough to solve your problem; you really haven't given us anything to work with.

Comment: Thank you and @Vimsha. Yes, I did need to actually supply a working example. I edited my original post with my current class that needs some work. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be really difficult to answer your question without code samples. But I am going to try my best with this example

```
class A
  def get_hash
    {"A"=>"1", "B"=>"2"}
  end
end 

class B
  def process_hash(hash)
   #do something with the hash
  end
end

hash = A.new.get_hash
B.new.process_hash(hash)
```